# Find out if the Ruler in PowerPoint is visible with VSTO

Tags: c#, vba, vsto, powerpoint

**How can I check whether the ruler in PowerPoint design mode is visible/active from C# VSTO?**

I have searched for hours in the PowerPoint object model. Have I missed the obvious, or isn't there a flag specifying whether the ruler is visible or not?

**Are there any other workarounds available to check whether the ruler is on or not?** (I don't need to adjust the ruler visibility, just read the value).

---

### Old non-working work-around specified below (kept to keep the comments relevant)

As a workaround I have tried to extend the ribbon and read the value of the checkbox defined as idMso="ViewRulerPowerPoint"

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI onLoad="Ribbon_Load" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <commands>
      <command idMso="ViewRulerPowerPoint" onAction="OnRulerAction" />
    </commands> 
</customUI>
```

**Callback**

```
public void OnRulerAction(Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonControl control, bool pressed)
{
    Debug.Print("Checkbox pressed");
}
```

But I just receive the following error message:

```
Callback signature mismatch: OnRulerAction
```

I have tried for hours to find a suitable callback signature, but none of my attempts have been successful.

Comment: hmmm I'm not well-versed in c# but the documentation suggests `public void OnRuleAction(Office.IRibbonControl control, bool pressed)`.  Does that make a difference, or do you still get mismatch error?

Comment: @DavidZemens Can you point me to the place in the documentation where you have read this? In my attempts Office.IRibbonControl cannot be resolved. I'm almost using the same though, and I will update the code example to include the fully qualified path of the interface.

Comment: In many code samples, Office just points to `Microsoft.Office.Core`, which you already have in the `OnRulerAction` method.

Comment: @Gedde it was on MSDN but I don't have the link handy ( tried to find it again this morning, but other examples like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.iribboncontrol.aspx) omit that qualifier, so apparently that was a red herring). In any case, it looks like you have an accepted answer already :)

Comment: @DavidZemens Thanks. As Olle explained, it is an alias for the qualified path I used, thus I don't need the documentation link anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VBA you can check if the checkbox is checked or not by using the following command, which will return `True` or `False`:

```
Application.CommandBars.GetPressedMso("ViewRulerPowerPoint")
```

In a C# VSTO add-in you can re-write this code as:

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CommandBars.GetPressedMso("ViewRulerPowerPoint")
```